# ClassNotFoundException: org.jacoco.agent.rt.RT

Tags: android, jacoco

I want to use Jacoco to collect code coverage for manually testing my Android apps. What I did was implement a Broadcast Receiver and ask Jacoco to collect coverage data when receiving the intent. Here is my receiver code:

```
public class CoverageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String TAG = "JacocoInstrumentation:";
    private static final String DEFAULT_COVERAGE_FILE_PATH = "/sdcard/coverage.ec";


    private static final boolean LOGD = true;

    private String mCoverageFilePath;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        generateCoverageReport();
    }

    private void generateCoverageReport() {
        if (LOGD)
            Log.d(TAG, "generateCoverageReport()");

        java.io.File coverageFile = new java.io.File(getCoverageFilePath());
        OutputStream out = null;
        // We may use this if we want to avoid refecltion and we include
        // emma.jar
        //RT.dumpCoverageData(coverageFile, false, false);
        // Use reflection to call emma dump coverage method, to avoid
        // always statically compiling against emma jar
        try {
            Object agent = Class.forName("org.jacoco.agent.rt.RT")
                    .getMethod("getAgent")
                    .invoke(null);
            out = new FileOutputStream(coverageFile,false);
            out.write((byte[]) agent.getClass().getMethod("getExecutionData", boolean.class)
                    .invoke(agent, false));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            reportJacocoError("Jacoco.jar not in the class path?", e);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            reportJacocoError(e);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            reportJacocoError(e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            reportJacocoError(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            reportJacocoError(e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            reportJacocoError(e);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            reportJacocoError(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            reportJacocoError(e);
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    reportJacocoError(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String getCoverageFilePath() {
        if (mCoverageFilePath == null) {
            return DEFAULT_COVERAGE_FILE_PATH;
        } else {
            return mCoverageFilePath;
        }
    }

    public boolean setCoverageFilePath(String filePath){
        if(filePath != null && filePath.length() > 0) {
            mCoverageFilePath = filePath;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private void reportJacocoError(Exception e) {
        reportJacocoError("", e);
    }

    private void reportJacocoError(String hint, Exception e) {
        String msg = "Failed to generate Jacoco coverage. " + hint;
        Log.e(TAG, msg, e);
    }


}
```

I also add apply the `plugin: 'jacoco'` and `testCoverageEnabled = true` in the Gradle file.

I have seen a few people do this, so it should work. However, when I tried to broadcast the triggering intent and my receiver began to work, I got a ClassNotFoundException:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jacoco.agent.rt.RT
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.jacoco.agent.rt.RT" on path:
...
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jacoco.agent.rt.RT
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

I have tried to specify the Jacoco version, or add Jacoco to the dependencies, but none of that worked. So what should I do?